# How to get the culture of an IFormatProvider

Tags: c#, globalization

i am converting strings to values using a culture specified to me as a `IFormatProvider`.

i am trying to figure out which culture they gave me.

i realize that `IFormatProvider` doesn't necessarily have to correspond to a `System.Globalization.Culture`, but it did.

So how can i get its name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `CultureInfo` class implements `IFormatProvider` so you may try casting:

```
IFormatProvider provider = ...
CultureInfo ci = provider as CultureInfo;
if (ci != null)
{
    string name = ci.DisplayName;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Took me about 20 minutes of cursing and swearing to figure out why `ci.Name` was returning an empty string. It was because in the culture used `ci.Name` ***was*** an empty string. Changed answer to use `DisplayName`. But excellent!